# Numpy.tensordot giving error "tuple index out of range"

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to create a vectorized version of PyTorch's conv2d function. In the code, I have a matrix representing the views of the size of the kernel, and I need to dot product it with the filter weights. The code looks like this

```
blocks # shape: (a, b, c, d, e, f)
filters # shape: (d, e, f, g)
# goal output size: (a, b, c, g)

return np.tensordot(blocks, filters, axes=([3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2]))
```

This is giving me the error "IndexError: tuple index out of range", and I'm not quite sure why. How should I go about fixing this? (Potentially using np.einsum to replace this?)

Comment: Just reading it, it looks ok, but I'd have to test an example.  Is there a traceback?

Comment: @hpaulj Yeah the callback is just:
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 100, in <module>
    main()
  File "", line 67, in conv2d
    res = np.tensordot(blocks, filters, axes=((3, 4, 5), (0, 1, 2)))
  File "", line 5, in tensordot
  File "", line 1068, in tensordot
    if as_[axes_a[k]] != bs[axes_b[k]]:
IndexError: tuple index out of range```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most general test, but enough to test the basic parameters:

```
In [85]: blocks = np.ones((2,2,2,3,3,3)); filters=np.ones((3,3,3,4))
In [86]: res = np.tensordot(blocks, filters, axes=([3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2]))
In [87]: res.shape
Out[87]: (2, 2, 2, 4)
```

`tensordot` reshapes the arguments to (2,2,2,27) and (27,4) and does a `dot`.  A elements of `res` are 27.

With a deliberate error:

```
In [89]: res = np.tensordot(blocks, filters, axes=([3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 2]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-89-370e50bf3a02>", line 1, in <module>
    res = np.tensordot(blocks, filters, axes=([3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 2]))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in tensordot
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1102, in tensordot
    if as_[axes_a[k]] != bs[axes_b[k]]:
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: When I tried that with the exact shapes that the errors were on, it worked fine when using np.ones, but it doesn't work in my actual program; not sure what that is about

Comment: Are you sure about the dimensions of the actual arguments?

Comment: Yeah, I'm printing out the shapes right before and it's telling me the shapes are right